# Reading info inside a node of an XML using dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, properties

```
<cat number="35">
 <eye>brown</eye>
 <tail>long</tail>
</cat>
<dog number="35">
 <eye>green</eye>
 <tail>short</tail>
</dog>
```

I've loaded an XML like this into a dataset, and to access info i'm just using this:

```
ds.Tables(cat).Rows(0)(eye) //returns brown
```

but i'd like to get the cat's number, how do i access this information using one line code to access one at a time (not some routine that loads every 'inside node property' (?) in an array or something) ?

Comment: do you really need to use a dataset? what about XMLDocument or LINQ ?

Comment: DUPE, i'm sorry, it happened because i didn't know the name of attributes in xml's, so it didn't show up in my preliminary search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something which stackoverflow returned on search.

This might give you something to start off with.Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904748/how-can-i-read-an-xml-attribute-using-readxml-how-does-dataset-readxml-translate)

Cheers :-) .. Hope that helped..

Comment: I'm sorry, what caused this is because i didn't know it's name was attribute, otherwise it would have appeared in my search, thank you